# Using m4 macros stored in one file on another file

Tags: m4

I would like to store some elementary m4 macros that I typically use in a a separate file (say `mymacros.m4` ) and then apply the macros used therein on the current source file I am working on `mydoc.pre.txt`

Is this possible? In all m4 tutorials, I have seen m4 macros being stored at the top of the file or interleaved with the working document. So at the commandline, I would like to type something like
`m4 -f mymacros.m4 mydoc.pre.txt > mydoc.post.txt`.

Is there an m4 feature for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m4` provides `include` and `sinclude` macros (and maybe `paste`, `spaste`):

> **include**   The defining text for the include macro shall be the
> contents of the file named by the first argument. It
> shall be an error if the file cannot be read. The
> behavior is unspecified if include is not immediately
> followed by a left-parenthesis.

> **sinclude**  The sinclude macro shall be equivalent to the include
> macro, except that it shall not be an error if the file
> is inaccessible.  The behavior is unspecified if
> sinclude is not immediately followed by a left-
> parenthesis.

So you can include your `mymacros.m4` into your `m4` files:

```
include(`mymacros.m4')
```

You can use (if your `m4` supports) the `-I` option of `m4` command to add directories to include path.